# How can I allow <span> and <div> with styling using OWASP?

Tags: java, owasp

In the following code:

```
private static final PolicyFactory POLICY_DEFINITION = new HtmlPolicyBuilder()
    .allowElements("span")
    .allowWithoutAttributes("span")
    .allowAttributes("style").onElements("span")
//    .allowStyling()
     .toFactory()
```

The second I add `allowStyling()` then any span element immediately fails. In other words I want to allow styling overall but the only way I could get it to work with `<span>` or `<div>` was to add them manually like the above. However when I want to add styling to other elements such as `<p>` then it all has to be done manually and cannot just be called through `allowStyling()`.

I did find this report but it's some years old and the solution doesn't work (what inspired the above code). Even if you put `allowStyling()` before or after the above code block.

The library I'm using is: https://owasp.org/www-project-java-html-sanitizer/

Comment: OWASP is an organization. What library are you using exactly?

Comment: https://owasp.org/www-project-java-html-sanitizer/

Comment: Please, could you provide a failing test case? `HtmlPolicyBuilder builder = new HtmlPolicyBuilder()
        .allowStyling()
        .allowElements("div", "span)
        .toFactory();` doesn't work? Please, consider review the [tests cases](https://github.com/OWASP/java-html-sanitizer/blob/main/src/test/java/org/owasp/html/HtmlPolicyBuilderTest.java) and [this example policy](https://github.com/OWASP/java-html-sanitizer/blob/35c506cfd452dba634202f13a7cc2e2a63ad7ee0/src/main/java/org/owasp/html/examples/EbayPolicyExample.java#L124) provided for the library, I think they will be of help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow styling overall you have to specify the allowed elements like `<span>`,`<div>` or `<p>` explicitly because the OWASP Sanitizer is white-list filter and not a blacklist filter based. Only then you can use `.allowStyling()` properly.

There are some convenience helpers like `.allowCommonInlineFormattingElements()` in the factory builder such that you do not have to list the element names. You should be able to allow styling for all elements with:

```
var POLICY_DEFINITION = new HtmlPolicyBuilder()
                .allowCommonBlockElements()
                .allowCommonInlineFormattingElements()
                .allowStyling()
                .toFactory();
```